# Do there exist cancellable manifolds?

Tags: manifolds, compact-manifolds

I do not know whether there exists a terminology for that property, but let us say that a closed manifold $C$ is cancellable if for every closed manifolds $M_1$ and $M_2$, $C \times M_1$ and $C \times M_2$ are homeomorphic iff $M_1$ and $M_2$ so are. My question is:

> Does there exist a closed cancellable $n$-manifold for any $n \geq 1$?

In fact, I even do not know whether there exists such a manifold in one dimension.

**Motivation:** It seems to be a common belief that the classification of closed (ie. connected, compact, boundaryless) manifolds (up to homeomorphism) becomes harder as the dimension increases. However, I did not find justifications for such an affirmation; moreover, it seems to be harder to solve Poincaré's conjecture in dimension three.

But if there existed a cancellable $n$-manifold $C$, then classifying $(n+k)$-manifolds would be at least as hard as classifying $k$-manifolds.

Comment: Isn't $\mathbb R^n$ an example?

Comment: $\mathbb{R}^n$ is not a closed manifold.

Comment: $\mathbb{R}^n$ is NOT an example. The whitehead manifold, $W$ is not homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^3$ but $\mathbb{R} \times W \simeq \mathbb{R}^4$. So $\mathbb{R}$ is not a cancelable manifold.

Answer (score 4):

If a manifold $C$ has Euler characteristic $0$, then it is not cancelable, so for instance no odd dimensional manifold is cancelable. I will sketch the argument, which makes use of the basic properties of Whitehead torsion, including the s-cobordism theorem.  The question asked about homeomorphism; the argument would work (and indeed has fewer technical prerequisites) in the smooth or PL setting, where the theory of Whitehead torsion and the s-cobordism theorem is simpler.  It takes a fair amount of technical work to establish those theorems in the topological setting.

Start with a pair of manifolds of dimension at least $5$, say $N_1$ and $N_2$ that are h-cobordant but not homeomorphic. These aren't so easy to come by, but you can find a discussion of some examples of this eg in this [Mathoverflow post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/125935/cancellation-law-for-mn-times-mathbb-r-nn-times-mathbb-r). Let $W$ be an h-cobordism between $N_1$ and $N_2$; this means that the boundary of $W$ is $N_1 \cup N_2$ and the inclusion maps $N_i \to W$ are homotopy equivalences. Let $\tau(W,N_1)$ be the Whitehead torsion of this h-cobordism; this is an element of the Whitehead group of the fundamental group of $W$ (and $N_1$ and $N_2$ for that matter.) The key property is that if $\tau(W,N_1) = 0$ then $W$ is homeomorphic to a product.

The product theorem for torsion (Kwun and Szczarba, Product and sum theorems for Whitehead torsion, Ann. of Math. 82, 183-190) says that the torsion $(W \times C, N_1 \times C)$ is $\tau$ times the Euler characteristic of $C$, and so by assumption must vanish.  By the s-cobordism theorem, $W \times C$ is homeomorphic to $N_1 \times C \times I$, so passing to the boundary gets that $N_1 \times C$ is homeomorphic to $N_2 \times C$.

I would bet that a similar argument proves that there is no cancelable manifold at all.  One approach would be to find, for every natural number $k$, non-homeomorphic manifolds $N_1(k)$ and $N_2(k)$ as above, where the torsion of an h-cobordism $W(k)$ between them is an element of order $k$ in the Whitehead group. (So the torsion is torsion, so to speak!) Then for $\chi{(}C{)} = k$, you would multiply by $W(k)$ to get an example as above.  But I have no idea how to construct such pairs $N_i(k)$.

Answer (score 1):

There was a post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/396608/does-x-times-s1-cong-y-times-s1-imply-that-x-times-mathbb-r-cong-y-times-ma/410699#410699) on math stackexchange answering in the negative for dimension 1. i.e. the circle is *not* a cancelable manifold. They establish that there are manifolds with different homotopy types whose products with the circle are diffeomorphic.

In the same post they reference [this](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2FBFb0060894#page-1) paper which establishes that the odd dimensional spheres are not cancelable. (I haven't done more than briefly scan the paper).

This appears in general to be a pretty tricky question to answer. There are results about unique factorization of simply connected Riemannian manifolds, but I haven't been able to find any results relating to any other category of manifolds.