# Homeomorphisms of product spaces: an example

Tags: examples-counterexamples, geometric-topology

In the first of these lectures (http://www.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/node/4436) given by M. Freedman he says that there exists (compact metric) spaces $X$ and $Y$ such that $X\times S^{1}$ is homeomorphic to $Y\times S^{1}$ but $X\times \mathbb{R}$ is not homeomorphic to $Y\times\mathbb{R}$.

Does anyone know an example of such spaces?

Comment: This question has better chance to be answered at mathoverflow.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I'll put it also there!

Comment: Also check references in http://www.morfismos.cinvestav.mx/Portals/0/SiteDocs/Articulos/Volumen2/No1/Santillan/santillan.pdf: Maybe one of them will answer your question.

Comment: On Mathoverflow I was suggested to look at: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/396608/does-x-times-s1-cong-y-times-s1-imply-that-x-times-mathbb-r-cong-y-times-ma/410699#410699 (It is indeed the same question, and even the source was the same)

Comment: Good. This means that your question can now be closed as a duplicate.